Handling custom properties in JSON without handling other properties in custom converter
Using Genson, I need to inject some custom properties from within a custom Converter (class-specific). This is accomplished in the serialize method with a simple writer.writeName("customProperty"), followed by a ctx.genson.serialize(...) with the wanted object.
After that step, I'd like the default property serialization mechanism to continue the object serialization so that I don't need to separately handle every property of this object (and having to update the custom serializer each time the class changes properties).
Similarly, I will need to properly deserialize my custom properties without having to handle the rest of them.
I have no clue how to do this or if it is even possible.
Addendum follows
Because I was asked to provide a sample... a sample class follows
public class SoSample {

  String someString = "Some string";
  int someInt = 42;
  float someFloat = 3.14f;
  List<Integer> intList = List.of(6, 5, 3);

  public static class SoSampleConverter implements Converter<SoSample> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SoSample object, ObjectWriter writer, Context ctx) throws Exception {
      writer.beginObject();
      //write custom property
      writer.writeName("customProp").writeValue("some value");
      //serialize the object as usual
      //???
      writer.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public SoSample deserialize(ObjectReader reader, Context ctx) throws Exception {
      reader.beginObject();
      //deserialize customProp
      if (reader.hasNext()) {
        reader.next();
        //first property should always be "customProp"
        String customProp = reader.valueAsString();
        //do something with "customProp"
      }

      //usual deserialization
      SoSample o;
      //???

      reader.endObject();
      return o;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Genson genson = new GensonBuilder()
      .withConverter(new SoSampleConverter(), SoSample.class)
      //other settings
      .setSkipNull(false)
      .useRuntimeType(true)
      .useClassMetadata(true)
      .useIndentation(true)
      .create();
    String json = genson.serialize(new SoSample());
    System.out.println(json);
  }
}

Running main should generate something like the following:
{
  "@class":"SoSample",
  "customProp":"some value",
  "intList":[
    6,
    5,
    3
  ],
  "someFloat":3.14,
  "someInt":42,
  "someString":"Some string"
}


Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
